# Excel vba Round of decimal for 2 points or to entire sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to remove decimal value after 2 points or round of 2 digits

I have tried below code, display has changed but cell value is with decimal only

Selection.NumberFormat = 0#

Example value - 212582.397228849

Comment: I want to apply for entire sheet not for one cell

Comment: It's possible but for the entire workbook, by setting `Range.NumberFormat = "0.00"` and `ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True`

Comment: Thanks @FlorentB. Its working fine after applying PrecisionAsDisplayed  true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the format of any particular column by:

```
Range("A1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#.00" '---> here Column is A
```

Or if you want to change format for a range:

```
Sub rounding()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E20") '--->enter your range here
    r.NumberFormat = "#0.00"
    ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True
End Sub
```

Comment: HI This is the code I have tried, But problem is it is just a display, If i try to access the value by cells(1,1).Value it showing the full decimal value.

Comment: Is there anyway to apply PrecisionAsDisplayed = True to another sheet

Comment: Because am opened existing workbook and doing, so I want to apply this PrecisionAsDisplayed  there If I try this objBasesheet.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True its showing object not supporting

Comment: @JGK - What is `objBasesheet` here, a workbook or a worksheet. `PrecisionAsDisplayed` works only with workbook object and hence will not work with worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True After adding this piece of code after 
changing the format then it is working fine

Thanks guys

```
Sub rounding()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E20") '--->enter your range here
    r.NumberFormat = "#0.00"
ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True 
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below

```
Sub decimalcheck()
    Dim a As Integer
    Debug.Print Format(Range("G3").Value, "#.00")
End Sub
```